# PHP - Import CSV into mysqli

Tags: php, html, csv, mysqli, import

I am trying to save cvs file in the server and after importing them into a sql Table. I have no issue saving the file however, the file is not imported into the table.

Here the code

html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="import_list_form"> 
Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" name="import_list_send" value="Upload" /> 
</form>
```

and php:

```
if(isset($_POST['import_list_send'])){
    $uploaddir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
    $file_imported = $_FILES['uploaded']['name']; 
    $upload_location = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'uploads/';
    $upload_location_final = $upload_location . basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
    $delimiter = ',';
    echo '<pre>';


    if ($_FILES['uploaded']['type'] == 'text/csv'){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
        echo "<p style='float:right;' class='print_msg'>File is valid, and was successfully uploaded in:</p>";
        echo "<p style='float:right;' class='print_msg'><a href='$upload_location_final' target='_blank'>" . $upload_location_final . "</a></p>";
        mysqli_query($conn, "LOAD DATA INFILE '$upload_location_final' INTO `Table`");    

    }else{
        echo "<p style='float:right;' class='print_msg'>File is not valid! Please make sure you have selected a CSV file.</p>";
    }

    print "</pre>";

}
```

Any Idea How can I get the file to upload the database table?

Comment: Annoying small fix here, instead of `LOAD DATA INFILE` do `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

Comment: It is likely that there is somthing in the .csv that MySQL does not like or cannot cope with. WIthout seeing the .csv file its difficult to say what the problem is

Comment: can you please describe how the expected bahavior differs from the actual behavior?

Comment: @RiggsFollyIf I Import the same csv file from myphpadmin it works just fine.

Comment: @Andrew added LOCAL still not working

Comment: The expected behaviour would be that the data in the csv file is added to the database table. The actual behaviour is that the data is not added

Comment: @SNos make sure that the CSV is formatted properly and you're ignoring the first row if it's not related to the data you wish to insert.

Comment: @Andrew I have also added IGNORE 1 LINES but nothing. I think the csv file is formatted properly because if I import from mysql admin it is imported fine.

Comment: Is $upload_location_final the right path?

Comment: Columns separated with: ,
Columns enclosed with: "
Columns escaped with: "
Lines terminated with: au                            ----------------------- how can I add this to query?